# Can SSL offloading be configured when using the Application Gateway Ingress Controller?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I am using the [Azure Application Gateway Ingress Controller](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress) for Kubernetes. I was able to successfully configure the controller to expose my Kubernetes Services over http. However, I would like the Application Gateway to do SSL offload. So that the Application Gateway will handle https requests, and then forward a plain http request to my Kubernetes service. Currently the [Ingress Controller documentation for https](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#expose-services-over-https) requires you to specify the certificate for your Kubernetes Service.

Is it possible to configure the Ingress Controller to do SSL offload so that I don't have to configure https on my Kubernetes Services?

Comment: Maybe you are searching for [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/33683956-application-gateway-ssl-offload-owasp-header-sup).

Comment: That looks like a feature request someone proposed for the Application Gateway. So I can't use it to fix my problem.

Comment: Application gateway supports SSL termination at the gateway, after which traffic typically flows unencrypted to the backend servers. This feature allows web servers to be unburdened from costly encryption and decryption overhead. This is the feature of Application Gateway. But application gateway supports end to end SSL encryption. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview#secure-sockets-layer-ssl-termination).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume [this](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md) is the document you are looking for.

```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: guestbook
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
  spec:
    tls:
      - secretName: <guestbook-secret-name>
    rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: frontend
            servicePort: 80
```

ps. no idea why you would use application gateway with k8s. its garbage.

Comment: I referenced that document in my question. That configuration requires the Kubernetes service to have the certificate and receive requests over https. This is what I'm trying to avoid. I only want the Application Gateway to receive requests over https, handle SSL for me, and then forward a plain http request to my Kubernetes services.

Comment: why do you think that is true? you often see ssl on port 80? or end-to-end ssl on ingress? also, this is not a service, this is an ingress config, so you are wrong on that one. service cannot have ssl, this is the certificate for application gateway

Comment: Thanks, you are right I was confusing the concept of a service and ingress, and you were also right that the certificate is for the application gateway. My confusion was partly coming from the fact that we had to save the certificate for the application gateway in kubernetes, which seemed odd to me. But it looks like that was done because the ingress controller needs access to the certificate when it updates the configuration for the Application gateway. Following the instructions you referenced worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"` annotation with properly configured TLS certificate on ingress enables us to configure Application Gateway to automatically redirect HTTP URLs to their HTTPS counterparts. i.e. it creates https & http listener on Application Gateway